# Angular: multiple ng-if problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, if-statement

I validate an emailaddress in my controller. When there is an error, I would like to show a error-message...

In this scenario, the user types in: **myname@email** (invalid)

The validation is working fine and my scope is as following:

```
Object {
    email_used: false,
    email_invalid: true,
    email_required: false
}
```

In my template, the error class on the input field works correctly:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mailadres" ng-model="new_user.email" class="grid-100" ng-class="(error_register.email_used || error_register.email_invalid || error_register.email_required) ? 'error' : ''"/>
```

... but my error message is not shown?

```
<!-- ERRORS -->
<span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_used" ng-cloak>Email is used<span>
<span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_required" ng-cloak>Email required<span>
<span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_invalid" ng-cloak>Email invalid<span>
<!-- / ERRORS -->
```

(I'm using Angular 1.2.0)

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: we will need more code to help you, there is nothing to spot yet in the piece of code you posted.
and btw - why the heck are you using angular 1.2 ? you should update asap... there are tons of security holes in such an old version of angular. the current version is 1.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed your span tags.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.error_register = {
    email_used: false,
    email_invalid: true,
    email_required: false
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_used" ng-cloak>Email is used</span>
  <span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_required" ng-cloak>Email required</span>
  <span class="ngdialog-form-error" ng-if="error_register.email_invalid" ng-cloak>Email invalid</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx... wth... :-)

Comment: No problem. It's easy to overlook small things like that. Originally I thought it might be a problem with the underscores in your object names and spent 5 minutes playing around with the names before I realized. If this solved your question, please accept the answer.